# Webpack tree shaking not working between packages

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler

Good evening!

I have been trying for a few days to get tree shaking between different packages to work.

Before going further, I have created a minimum repro that I will explain throughout this post: https://github.com/Apidcloud/tree-shaking-webpack

I have also opened an issue on webpack repo: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8951

For simplicity sake, the example just uses webpack. **Babel is not used**.

The above example has two packages, both with their respective bundle:

- `core` - exports 2 functions, `cube` and `unusedFn`
- `consumer` - imports `cube` from `core` and exports its own function, `consumerFn`

### Core package

[image: core package]

Note that `square` function is not exported in the `index.js` file. It's a way to know that tree shaking is indeed working within `core` at least, as it's not included in the final bundle (which is correct).

### Consumer package

[image]

As you can see, only `cube` is being imported from `core`. It then exports its own function (`consumerFn`) consuming `cube`.

### Problem

The problem is that the `consumer` bundle is including everything from the `core` bundle. That is, it's including `unusedFn` when it shouldn't, resulting in a bigger bundle.

Ultimately, the goal is to do the same in a monorepo with multiple packages. There's no point on having them if each package is bundling the everything from the others. The goal is to bundle only what's necessary for each package.

Using `optimizationBailout` I can see that **ModuleConcatenation** plugin is issuing some warning messages. I also used `--verbose` flag:
[image]

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    core: './src/index.js',
    consumer: './consumer/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // for simplicity sake I removed the UMD specifics here.
    // the problem is the same, with or without it.
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
    sideEffects: true
  },
  stats: {
    // Examine all modules
    maxModules: Infinity,
    // Display bailout reasons
    optimizationBailout: true
  }
};
```

I also have `"sideEffects": false` in the `package.json`.

I went through webpack's [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) too, but I'm not sure what is missing.

### Related issues:

- [webpack-3-babel-and-tree-shaking-not-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663486/webpack-3-babel-and-tree-shaking-not-working?rq=1)
- [webpack-including-unused-exports-in-final-bundle-not-tree-shaking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599352/webpack-including-unused-exports-in-final-bundle-not-tree-shaking)

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Hopefully someone can answer. My guess is that at some point during bundling the module is being converted to CJS and from that point forward it can no longer drop unused members (thus that warning above that it can not concat `.../dist/core.js` - I'm assuming that content in `/dist/` has already been compiled.

Comment: Yup, `dist` folder is for the bundles.

Comment: Can u update to webpack 4?

Comment: It's already the latest version

Comment: facing the same issue

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any Update on this?